# Why is $()^{n}:\mathbf{G}_{m}\longrightarrow\mathbf{G}_{m}$ surjective in the $fppf$ topology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, flatness

Let $X$ be a scheme. Why is $()^{n}:\mathbb{G}_{m}\longrightarrow\mathbf{G}_{m}$ surjective in the category $X_{fppf}$?

(Here $\mathbf{G}_{m}(X)=X\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[T,X]/(XT-1))$ is the multiplicative group scheme.)

In other words: Why does that map come from a faithfully flat morphism?

How does that relate to the case where one uses the Zariski topology instead of $fppf$?

A reference may be nice.

Comment: include a definition of $\mathbb{G}_m$ - how do you define this as a group scheme?

Comment: @hm2020 What do you mean?

Comment: This map $\mathbb{G}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m$ comes on structure rings from the endomorphism $T \longmapsto T^n$ of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[T,1/T]$. Unless I’m mistaken, this map is free of rank $n$ (with basis $(1,T,\ldots,T^{n-1})$).

Comment: @TheThinWhistler - The map $\phi(t):=t^n$ is injective, hence your map $()^n$ is a dominant morphism of affine group schemes. Since $\mathbb{G}_m$ is irreducible it follows $()^n$ is schematically surjective. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: @TheThinWhistler - There is an exercise in HH (Ex.II.2.18) giving the relation between the notion "schematically surjective morphism" for affine schemes and injectivity of the corresponding ring morphism. It says $()^n$ is dominant iff $\phi$ is injective.